# How to implement countdown timer

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET using C#: Hi,
I am developing an on line test application. All test are timed. Duration is 60 minutes.. I want to implement countdown time which time decreases by seconds. Somewhere on my page time remaining should be displayed. Like 59:59, 59:58, 59:57... After 60 mins is over the test should automatically be submitted. Before 60 mins also we can also submit the test.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://stuntsnippets.com/javascript-countdown/
You also need to submit the page after 3600 seconds, so do this:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3600" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

And on the server side

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement the timer withour javascript? do we need to specify protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
on the page load event?

Comment: You need the javascript for the timer. you don't need to specify Timer1_Tick inside the Page_Load event, it's a separate event. Have a look at these links: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-timer-control and http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/IntroToTimerControl.aspx